# Add admin user to powerforms DocuSign

Tags: docusignapi, powerform

DocuSign is used to send Submitted signed forms to the admin user (The email id used to create the DocuSign account). I have created a new admin user. But the newly created admin user has not received the submitted signed forms as the previous admin user. Am I missing something in the configurations or settings?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not clear if you created a new user or a new account.
I suspect you created a new account and the a new user that is the admin for this account.
The sender of an envelope should automatically receive the completed document if you have this checked in the *Settings* panel under *Email Notifications*:

(sorry this image has the wrong highlighted line, the one you need is the one on top of it - *An envelope is Completed*)
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will check it.